# 301 Redirect TLD with country domain to another domain

Tags: regex, apache, redirect, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-301

I'm trying to redirect a TLD to a different domain entirely and am beginning to pull my hair out trying to get to the bottom of it:

Here's an example origin domain:

```
www.foo.com.au
```

and the intended destination redirect:

```
www.bar.com/subpage
```

As it stands now, here's the rule I have written that returns a 200 response when testing with curl:

```
RewriteCond %(HTTP_HOST) ^(?:www\.)?foo\.com\.au$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.bar.com/subpage [R=301,L]
```

Anything you can point out would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured this one out, guys.

The rewrite rule/condition was correct save for one thing..... curly braces instead of parentheses to encapsulate HTTP_HOST.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?foo\.com\.au$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.bar.com/subpage [R=301,L]
```

This code has the redirect working as expected.  Details, details.